# iOS14: automatically turn on or off second sim

Tags: iphone, ios, esim

I have an iPhone 12 Pro with iOS 14.2.1 and I need to automatically turn on or off the second sim based on my working hours schedule. Is there a way to achieve so?

Comment: I am not using the Shortcuts app so I can't test it, but I would guess that it is possible to do such things. Have a look over here: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/shortcuts/id915249334

Comment: If *Apple Shortcuts* can allow you to switch Airplane mode of second sim on and off, then @X_841 suggestion would work out perfectly for you.

Comment: I don't think this will be possible automatically. Have you looked into [Do Not Disturb](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204321) mode? I feel like this might get you closest to what you want. You can blacklist your office contacts and unknown callers and whitelist your friends during certain hours.

Comment: @sfxedit airplane mode works over the phone, not over the sim...so enabling it will turn off both my sim cards

Comment: @n1000 also “do not disturb” works over the phone rather than over the sim cards

Comment: Correct. Just trying to give you a hint for what you could do when you find that there is no way to automatically turn off one line. Another free idea for you would be to use call forwarding (to mailbox) instead. There seem to be some shortcuts out there that can do that.

Comment: @n1000 yes thanks. Can’t find the call forwarding shortcut you are talking about...where is it?

Comment: Aren't there option "Turn Off This Line"? Not heavy Shortcut user but couldn't this be used?

Comment: @Mark Android has an option to enable or disable a SIM in dual- or -tri- sim phones. [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/348348/333666) suggests that you can do something similar with ios on iPhone too. Please check if that works for you and whether you can control that using Apple shortcuts.

Comment: @sfxedit that is the procedure to toggle sim cards manually

Comment: @Mark Yes, and my thought was if it can be controlled by Shortcuts, it can do what you need.

Comment: @sfxedit I’m not getting it: it is a manual procedure, you can’t create a shortucut...or am I wrong?

Comment: @Mark I was asking you to verify if it can be controlled through shortcuts - I can't check because I don't have access to a dual sim iPhone.

Comment: @sfxedit ah ok, so I understood correctly...no, I can’t find any option about this in the shortcuts